# static method NSInvocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-foundation, nsinvocation

Is it possible to use NSInvocation for static method calls?

We're using NSInvocation to simplify our method calls in unit tests for non-public methods.

This works great for our instance methods, for which we provide an object and appropriate data to NSInvocation. However, can we do the same with static methods?

Comment: There are no "static methods" in Objective-C. There are "class methods", which are dynamically dispatched at runtime, not looked up statically at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Assuming your class is `MyClass` and your method is `+(void)myClassMethod:(id)sender;`, you can use:

```
NSMethodSignature *signature = [MyClass methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(myClassMethod:)];
```

Then you can provide the `NSMethodSignature` to your `NSInvocation` when created:

```
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
```

Comment: Note also that the `target` of a class method should be a class object. Something like `invocation.target = [MyClass class]`.